# Any idea why I am receiving this error? AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'reply_document'

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COSge.png)Any Idea why I am getting this error. I have tried googling this, error and I don't think I am missing any required packages.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your original token, delete it!

If guess the problem is with your file path, the file doesn't exist where you've pointed it to.